# Is mongodb handle query one by one?

Tags: mongodb

Assume I have a mongodb instance on a remote server (1 core cpu and 8G memory).
When I send a simple query `db.table.find({_id:ObjectId('xxx')}).limit(1).explain()`to the instance, I got the result show that query cost 10ms.
So can I come to a conclusion that "my mongodb server can only handle 100 simple query per second"?

Comment: How did you time that, from the web server? Then it would include the time taken to pass and process the data to the web service as well as any network latency depending where they are in relation to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"So can I come to a conclusion that "my mongodb server can only handle 100 simple query per second""

Its not tht like that 1 query takes 10ms  then 100 query will take 1sec
`db.table.find({_id:ObjectId('xxx')}).limit(1)` will not lock your table
So if your 100 client request this with 100 connections all will return in 10ms 
Concurrency Depends upon locks and connection limits

If a query locking collection for read and write for 10 sec then all  query after that will wait for lock to cleared

`MongoDb Can Handle multiple Request`

db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } )
will return current status  of mongo there is object in

```
"connections" : {
    "current" : <num>,
    "available" : <num>,
    "totalCreated" : <num>,
    "active" : <num>
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#connections

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.maxIncomingConnections

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/

These will give more clarity around connections and its limits

Answer (score 1):

You should know, your mongodb server can handle many parallel queries.

Answer (score -1):

your assumption is incorrect, cuz u are ignoring the fact that mongodb supports concurrency

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)